# Is there a way to pass a Counter as input into Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-layer, tf.keras, autoencoder

I have a dictionary of Counters (from [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html),) all keys are integers. I am trying to write an autoencoder which takes a Counter as input.

Naive attempts like `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(datastructure)` fail. My current method is to put each counter through a manual loop and create a sparse matrix, however this is extremely RAM and CPU intensive. I am hoping for a better solution. Ideas?

Note 1: I am using the Keras interface, in case that is relevant.

Here is an example which produces something with the same structure as my data, and then converts it inefficiently into a datastructure acceptable to Tensorflow:

```
from collections import Counter 
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(1)
datastructure = dict()

for i in range(5):
    x_key = int(random.uniform(1, 200))
    if x_key in datastructure:
        continue
    else:
        datastructure[x_key] = Counter()

    for j in range(3):
        y_key = int(random.uniform(1, 200))
        if y_key not in datastructure:
            datastructure[y_key] = Counter()      
        value = int(random.uniform(1, 4))
        datastructure[x_key][y_key] += value
        datastructure[y_key][x_key] += value

print("Original structure:")    
print(datastructure)


max_key = max(datastructure.keys())
trainable_datastructure = np.zeros_like([],shape = (max_key + 1, max_key + 1))

for i in datastructure:
    for j in datastructure[i]:
        trainable_datastructure[i][j] = datastructure[i][j]
        trainable_datastructure[j][i] = datastructure[i][j]
        
print("Trainable and inefficient structure:")
print(trainable_datastructure)
```

I've  used small values in the range to keep things simple, in my case the datasize is closer to 20 million by 20 million with a sparsity level of about 99.993%

Comment: Can you add some example data along with expected output and code samples of what you tried?

Comment: @AniketBote I have added an example. I'm not sure what you mean by expected output, I am trying to train an autoencoder.